# Refresh content of CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to refresh/update the content of an CKEDITOR instance. What I try to do is that I have replaced a textarea with ckeditor. Then some javascript changes the content of the replaced textarea. After this, the content of the CKEDITOR has to pull the new content from the Textarea. Is there any function I can call?

hope you guys know a soltuion...
Thaks

Answer (score 4):

You can use CKEDITOR.editor.setData:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData

Comment: Yes, but I have many instances I need to update at the same time. I would need to find a way to identify the CKEDITOR instance for each textarea.

Comment: Since the name of an Instance equals the id of each textarea, I can take this to get the content of the teaxtarea and use your suggestion of setData(). I would prefer a method call like CKEDITOR.instances[instance].refresh() or sort of. So if anyone else has a solution. but thanks so far!